# Upgrade Gradle to a new version for all projects in my IDE?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

W10 OS, Eclipse 4.10 IDE

I just upgraded Gradle to 5.4.1.  I did this by going (Cygwin):

```
$ ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.4.1
```

for all my different projects.  On the Gradle site it says this is the better way, rather than manually editing gradle-wrapper.properties.

After doing this, in Eclipse I then have to: highlight project and context menu --> Gradle --> Refresh Gradle for each project which takes a long time for each.

At the moment I only have about 10 active projects, and upgrading Gradle is not something you do every day, but as a matter of interest is there a quicker way doing an upgrade globally?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [Eclipse gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html#sec:eclipse_usage), you can run

```
./gradlew eclipse
```

in the root project and it will refresh all the sub-projects in Eclipse.